# How to put switch case statement inside a foreach loop in php?

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach, switch-statement

I have the following conditional statement inside the foreach loop. I want all the conditional statements to be checked. I hope that it would be able to done by using switch case statements. Can anyone give me an idea how to do that? or is there any other way to do that? some dates have the values regarding to all four conditions. they won't be check if i use this code. Since i am new to this its hard me to figure out how to do that. It would be a great help if anyone can give an idea.

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {

            if ($row->title == 'GK' && $row->type == 'AM') {
                $cal_data[substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)] = '<div class="gk_am">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
            }  if ($row->title == 'GK' && $row->type == 'PM') {
                $cal_data2[substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)] = '<div class="gk_pm">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
            } if ($row->title == 'RP' && $row->type == 'AM') {
                $cal_data3[substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)] = '<div class="rp_am">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
            } if ($row->title == 'RP' && $row->type == 'PM') {
                $cal_data4[substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)] = '<div class="rp_pm">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
            }     


        }
```

Comment: What are all the possible values may come for each variable `$row->title` and `$row->type`?

Comment: @Gunaseelan title is 'RP' or 'GK' and the type is 'AM' or 'PM'

Comment: then Rasclatt's answer and my answer will be enough for you to fulfill your requirement.

Answer (score 3):

Use else if condition instead of only If condition:

```
     foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        if ($row->title == 'GK' && $row->type == 'AM') {
            $cal_data[substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)] = '<div class="gk_am">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
        } elseif ($row->title == 'GK' && $row->type == 'PM') {
            $cal_data2[substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)] = '<div class="gk_pm">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
        } elseif ($row->title == 'RP' && $row->type == 'AM') {
            $cal_data3[substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)] = '<div class="rp_am">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
        } elseif ($row->title == 'RP' && $row->type == 'PM') {
            $cal_data4[substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)] = '<div class="rp_pm">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
        }     
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row) 
{
    switch($row->title)
    {
        case 'GK':
            switch($row->type)
            {
                case 'AM':
                    $cal_data[substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)] = '<div class="gk_am">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
                    break;
                case 'PM':
                    $cal_data2[substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)] = '<div class="gk_pm">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
                    break;
            }
        break;
        case 'RP':
            switch($row->type)
            {
                case 'AM':
                    $cal_data3[substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)] = '<div class="rp_am">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
                    break;
                case 'PM':
                    $cal_data4[substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)] = '<div class="rp_pm">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
                    break;
            }
        break;

    }
}
```

The above code is same as your given conditional code. Check it out.

You are recommended to use `switch` statements over `conditional` statements where we knew what are the possible values can come.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do the same thing with `switch-case` then this is one way to do it.

```
switch($row->title()){

  case 'GK':

    switch($row->type()){

      case 'AM':
      ......
      break;

    }

     break;


......
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
switch($row->title) {
    case 'GK': if($row->type=='AM'){
         $cal_data[substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)] = '<div class="gk_am">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
                }else{
                     $cal_data2[substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)] = '<div class="gk_pm">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
                }
                break ;
    case 'RP':  if($row->type=='AM'){
                    $cal_data3[substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)] = '<div class="rp_am">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
                }else{
                     $cal_data4[substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)] = '<div class="rp_pm">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
                }
                break ;     
    }
```

}

Try this

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it is actually far more complicated than it needs to be.

```
$all_cals = [
  'GK' => [
      'AM' => &$cal_data,
      'PM' => &cal_data2
  ],
  'RP' => [
      'AM' => &$cal_data3,
      'PM' => &cal_data4
  ]
];

foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
   $row_cal_data = $all_cals[$row->title][$row->type];
   if (isset($row_cal_data)) {
      $row_cal_data[substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)] = '<div class="'.tolower($row->title)."_".tolower($row->type).'">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
   }
}
```

No switch statements at all.

Comment: Here, 'gk_am','gk_pm','rp_am' and 'rp_pm' are css classes. I am just calling it within that div in order to get some styles.

Comment: @Stell Understood.  My example code should produce the exact same result as your code, though of course I haven't tested it.  There are likely better ways to structure your HTML, but I'd have to know more about your actual use-case.

Answer (score 1):

I think close to your scenario

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {

switch (true) {
                    case ($row->title == 'GK' && $row->type == 'AM'):
                     $cal_data[substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)] = '<div class="gk_am">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
                        break;
                    case ($row->title == 'GK' && $row->type == 'PM'):
                    $cal_data2[substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)] = '<div class="gk_pm">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
                        break;
                    case ($row->title == 'RP' && $row->type == 'AM'):
                    $cal_data3[substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)] = '<div class="rp_am">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
                        break;                      
                    case ($row->title == 'RP' && $row->type == 'PM'):
                    $cal_data4[substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)] = '<div class="rp_pm">' . $row->title . ' ' . $row->type . '</div>';
                        break;
                }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Forego the whole `switch` and such and use an `array`. You can likely do everything in one line by also using `strtolower()` for your class name. Your variable incrementing (`$cal_data1`,`$cal_data2`..etc.) instead just new values in your array so `$cal_data['date_cal'][0]`,`$cal_data['date_cal'][1]`...etc. It may make your code easier to work with:

```
<?php
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        // I am not sure if you wish to capture each instance,
        // but you have no if/elseif so I assume you are capturing
        // each instance.
        $cal_data[substr($row->date_cal, 8, 2)][]   =   '<div class="'.strtolower($row->title.'_'.$row->type).'">'.$row->title.' '.$row->type.'</div>';     
    } 
?>
```